# Retrieve search result on onchange event in form using php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to retrieve search results on onchange event in form using php mysql. Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE Html>
      <html>
       <head>
      <title>PHP INSERT UPDATE DELETE SEARCH</title>
     </head>
      <body>
    <form action="testing.php" method="post">
           <input type="number" name="clientId" placeholder="Id" value="<?php  echo $clientId;?>"><br><br>
           <input type="text" name="clientName" required placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $clientName;?>"><br><br>
          <input type="text" name="clientNo" required placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $clientNo;?>"><br><br>
           <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Age" value="<?php echo $address;?>"><br><br>
           <div>


               <!-- Input For Find Values With The given ID -->
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
            </div>
           </form>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: Do ajax call to get the data. This is the only way to call PHP functions from javascript.

Comment: On change of what event?

Comment: @Shubham do you have the test code like this???

Comment: @Jessedegans i want when user enter the id and press tab then other fields are automatically load

Answer (score 1):

## Server & client side

Web development is all about communication. In this case, communication between two (2) parties, over the HTTP protocol:

- The **Server** - This party is responsible for **serving** pages. (PHP in your case)
- The **Client** - This party *requests* pages from the **Server**, and displays them to the user. In most cases, the client is a **web browser** (html/ css / JavaScript).

  - The **User** - The user *uses* the **Client** in order to surf the web, fill in forms, watch videos online, etc.

Each side's programming, refers to code which runs at the specific machine, the server's or the client's.

You will need to create some php script that returns data and make a Jquery AJAX request to that php file.

## Easy example

Javascript:

```
  var someID = 1;
   $.post( "test.php", { id: someID, someothervalue: 2 })
    .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

PHP(`test.php`)

```
<?php

$someID=$_POST['someID'];
$someothervalue=$_POST['someothervalue'];

if($someID == 1)
{
  echo "JOHN";
}
else
{
  echo "error";
}

?>
```

An alert will be displayed with "Data Loaded: JOHN"

[More about Jquery GET and POST](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

[Some other usefull tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and Php are two different contexts. JS runs in browser and PHP in your server. You cannot call PHP function (like mysqli) from javascript.

To get new results you have two options => refresh page with new search and do a full roundtrip to server. Or use ajax to load new data and replace them into your page.

More reading on ajax:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ => If you are using jQuery

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest => XmlHttpRequest if you are using plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp) in order to fulfill your requirement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getMake(make) {
    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.open("POST","make.php");

    data.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(data.readyState === 4 && data.status === 200){
           document.getElementById('model').innerHTML = data.responseText;
        }
    }
    data.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    data.send('make='+make);
    }
</script>
```

HTML will look as follows:

```
<select name="make" id="make" onchange="getMake(this.value)"
```